# Installing php_svn windows & linux

Tags: php, windows, svn, pecl

I'm using a windows machine for local development and I'd like to install php_svn so I can write some code in php that provides an svn interface for a web app so that the client can download all their files easily.  The php4win site is down, and I can't find the php_svn.dll anywhere and running pecl.bat install svn doesnae work either.  "The DSP svn.dsp could not be found"  I'd be very grateful if anyone has any information on how I can install this php extension on windows, and the /pierre site doesn't seem to contain the php_svn extension within it.

Answer (score 0):

Just by doing a few quick searches on your request, I couldn't find it, either.  It looks like you'll either have to compile the library for Windows, yourself, or try the method that Björn mentions on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5636228/3257871).

> Alin, thanks for your effort. I ended up with using the svn command line client directly from php. Like this $Res = svn --non-interactive ls -R -v "file:///C:/Proj/Svn/..." and then parsing the result string.